# substituir caixa de cor por imagem no css

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde galera, seguinte
tenho umas caixas de texto que estão sendo formatadas via css
queria saber se é possivel trocar a formatação dessas caixas para imagens, sem ter que alterar a formatação na html principal ou das paginas de scripts.

segue o código

```
.box-wrapper{
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
}
#pag-1{
background-color: yellow;
}
#pag-2{
background-color: limegreen;
/*display: none;*/
}
#pag-3{
background-color: blue;
/*display: none;*/
}
#pag-4{
background-color: red;
/*display: none;*/
}
```

Comment: Você precisa alterar de cor para imagem ? é essa a dúvida ?

Comment: não, quero tirar esse box e colocar imagens que fiz, exemplo, apagar tudo e deixar o #pag-1{ e logo seguida um caminho pra uma imagem

Comment: box-wrapper são as class e pag são as divs, mas consegui aqui amigo, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo colocando imagem no lugar de cor, veja se resolve seu problema, caso contrario avise para edição da resposta.

```css
#page1{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
background-size: 200px;
  background-image:   url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/28221/pexels-photo-28221.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float:left;
}

#page2{
margin-left: 5px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: blue;
background-size: 200px;
  background-image:   url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ff/40/a6/ff40a667d68d2ab5d0b850eaa0664d82.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="page1"></div>
<div id="page2"></div>
```

Comment: muito obrigado man

Comment: Mandou bem porque estava difícil entender o que o autor queria com uma linguagem pouco convencional "caixa de cor" e sem o devido HTML

Comment: Verdade, deduzi a resposta quando questionei ele lá em cima nos comentários. Ainda bem que tudo deu certo.